# JSONP 414 (Request-URI Too Large)

Tags: javascript, json, jsonp

I'm trying to send huge amount of data (~50000 bytes) to another server using JSONP, but I get [414 (Request-URI Too Large)](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) response (JSONP allows only GET). Splitting the data to 2k chunks slows down a lot the whole app, so I'm looking for some other solution.

I've tried to change [LimitRequestLine directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/core.html#limitrequestline) in Apache's virtual host, but seems this has no effect, still the same error.

Any other ideas how to send to fix this problem? Maybe some other solution than [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Might be this help. I found it a long time ago & bookmark on Flickr.

[image]